# Smallest Algebra Containing Singletons

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, self-learning

$\Omega:=\mathbb N$. What is the smallest **algebra** containing all singleton $\{\omega\}$, i.e. $\{1\}, \{2\}$, and so on.  Any hint, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Finite* or *cofinite*, that’s the question.